# Ubuntu 20.10 nvidia-drivers and acpi problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, acpi, 20.10

I installed Ubuntu 20.10 from live usb on my asus notebook (model: fx505g) on SSD (actually the only drive on my pc) with Nvidia GTX1050Ti. It was very difficult as i encountered several problems, such as:

- grub installer failed on dev/sda (solved with live usb again after install -> boot-repair -> reboot)
- random freezes during install (solved setting acpi=off on boot)

When i finally managed to run OS, random freezes again; so acpi=off again. During installation from USB everything worked fine.

At this point the system is using xserver noveau drivers and graphics are smooth and responsive, but if i try to install any other nvidia property driver, the system run low and there is a ridicolous mouse input latency (with system boot time > 2m). With nvidia driver installed, if i run nvidia-smi i get

> "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA
> driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and
> running."

I tried to set acpi_osi=Linux from boot menu (even acpi_osi=Windows, just because i don't know what else i can do) and acpi_backlight=vendor: the system communicate fine with the Nvidia driver but the system is incredibly slow and everything crash. Also, no audio detected (only dummy output)

So i went back to xserver noveau drivers: at this point boot speed is quite normal but i can't use trackpad, power maanagement settings, bluethoot devices and audio.

Before going back to acpi=off i also tried with nomodeset which gave me low-res and still ultra-slow system; actually, the only way to get things work is with acpi=off with no trackpad, bluethoot, battery management and fn keyboard functions.

Is there a way to get things work together?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case someone else is struggling with similar problems: in the end, I just installed ubuntu 20.04 and added these boot parameters in `etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=assign-busses apicmaintimer idle=poll reboot=cold,hard snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"
```

Now everything works as it should.